# Como iterar array dentro de um ngFor angular/ionic

Tags: html, ionic, angular

Tenho o seguinte modelo:

```
export interface Perguntas{
     historico:[{id_historico: number, resposta_historico: string}]
}
```

No meu arquivo ts eu realizo uma requisição http para um serviço que me retorna esses dados preenchidos, se eu dou um console.log(this.perguntas), eu obtenho meus dados da seguinte maneira: 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu preciso iterar esses dados no meu template, eu tentei algo como:

```
<ion-card *ngFor="let pergunta of perguntas; let i = index">

<p>{{pergunta.data}}</p>
```

Aqui funciona corretamente, o meu problema está em iterar o array histórico, tentei:

```
<div class="message">{{pergunta.historico.pergunta_historico}}</div>
```

Porque não funciona? Nenhuma mensagem de erro é mostrada no meu console, porém o valor não é mostrado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O pergunta.historico também é um array. Você precisa fazer a iteração desse array. Algo como:

```
<div class="message" *ngFor="let historico of pergunta.historico> 
    {{historico.pergunta_historico}}
</div>
```